# How to get the source of the page loaded in IWebBrowser2?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

From a BHO (Browser Helper Object) in Internet Explorer, how do I get the full source code of the page currently loaded in the web browser when I have its IWebBrowser2 interface?

Do I have to download it again from the url where it resides or is there a way to get the copy that internet explorer downloaded and used to render the page?

I tried getting the outerHTML of the html element of the current document, but it returns the source code already preprocessed. I need to get it in the same form you see it when you clock "View Source Code" in the Internet Explorer.

Thank you for any helpful information!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the browser's `Document` property for `IPersistStream` or `IPersistFile` and then call its `Save()` method.  But when querying the browser for its HTML, you are likely to get the *processed* HTML, which may include DOM changes from scripts.

To get the *original* HTML, you should download it yourself directly from the source URL, or at least extract the file from the browser's local cache.

Comment: I ended up downloading the page from the source url. It feels kind of stupid downloading the page again knowing that IE has is stashed somewhere (it doesn't download it again when you click View Page Source) but I don't have the time to look for it.

Comment: That is why I suggested you load the file from the browser's cache before going to the server.  For instance, [`URLDownloadToFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123.aspx) checks the cache first. Or you can use [`GetUrlCacheEntryInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384185.aspx) to get the local filename of a cached URL.